# How do I change the X and Y of an arch texture based on a formula?

Tags: godot, gdscript, godot4

Basically, I'm trying to recreate the path when you wind up the slingshot in angry birds. I have an arch texture that I'm trying to change the x and y (and scale) to match with the output given by the angle, the initially velocity, etc.
Can someone write the formula out? I'm not proficient in math.

I havent tried anything yet, but thats because I don't know what formulas to use.

Answer (score 0):

The path of a projectile in ideal conditions is a parabola, which is described by the equations of motion ([projectile throw](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projectile_motion) in particular).

And yes, stretching your texture of a parabola should work  (see [There is only One True Parabola](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=hoh4TmPzu1w)).

---

Now, you say your input parameters are an angle and a <strike>velocity</strike> speed, which is not the usual way the equations of motion are written.

Start by making a velocity vector (I'll assume the angle is measured from the positive right axis):

```
var throw_velocity := Vector2.RIGHT.rotated(angle) * speed
```

Now the components of the velocity vector as own initial vertical speed, and initial horizontal speed, which is what we will work with.

However, we are lacking a variable. For, you see, the equation for a vertical throw links the following variables:

- initial vertical velocity
- air time
- gravitational acceleration
- maximum height

And I need two of them to be able to figure out the other two. But I only have the vertical velocity. Now, I know you do not know the maximum height, otherwise you would have known how to scale the texture vertically... So the question is: do you have the gravitational acceleration or the air time?

I'm going to bet you have the gravitational acceleration. So, given initial vertical velocity and gravitational acceleration, we compute the maximum height like this (assuming gravity has a positive value):

```
var max_height := (throw_velocity.y * throw_velocity.y) / (gravity * 2.0)
```

You can check the units, on top we have speed squared, that is distance over time squared (`distance^2/time^2`) and on the bottom we have acceleration (`distance/time^2`), so when you cancel out, you are left with distance. *The short explanation for the why there is a 2 dividing is that this is only half of the motion (the projectile first rises, and then falls, right in the middle we have the maximum height)*

Ok, so we know the vertical size of the parabola. What about the horizontal?

Well, horizontally it behaves like a linear motion (because in our model there is no acceleration horizontally)…

That means we need the air time:

```
var air_time := throw_velocity.y / gravity
```

*This is speed (`distance/time`) divided by acceleration (`distance/time^2`), and I hope you can see that gives us time.*

And with that we compute the throw distance:

```
var throw_distance := throw_velocity.x * air_time
```

*Multiplying speed (`distance/time`) by `time`, gives us the distance.*

And that is the horizontal size of the parabola:

```
var parabola_size := Vector2(throw_distance, max_height)
```

The scale is a matter of figuring out by what factor you need to multiply the size of the texture to get to the parabola size…

So the `texture_size * scale = parabola_size`, and by dividing by `texture_size` on both side we have `scale = parabola_size / texture_size`:

```
var parabola_size := Vector2(throw_distance, max_height)
var texture_size := texture.get_size()
var scale := parabola_size / texture_size
```

Et voilà.